# No Product matches the given query with Django

Tags: django

After I deleted a product from Django Admin Panel all the urls seems not to work anymore, not being able to access the admin or anything within my page and I don't really know where the problem might be. I change the debug mode from true to false but still the same. Maybe someone had this issue before.

this is my code

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product


# Create your views here.
def all_products(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, "products.html", {"products": products})
```

urls.py

```
             from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import all_products


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', all_products, name='products'),
    ]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='')
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'urls seems not to work anymore, not being able to access the admin or anything within my page'?  Please,  be more concrete. Do you have any errors?  Post them here.  Also,  what is 'my page'?

Comment: you have t oshow your problem more precisely, with your template please

Comment: My page is actually an ecommerce website that I am creating and it has some products as well. I logged in the admin panel to delete a product and right after I did that I got this error nothing it working anymore. This is the error I'm getting. As far as I can understand I need to have a view where I need to pass an id as a argument. Is this right?


Raised by:products.views.all_products
No Product matches the given query.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.